# Conway Complex Analysis Book, Exercise 1 - Section 1 and Chapter VIII (Runge's Theorem)

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying the book of John Conway (Functions of One Complex Variable), and in the Section of Runge's Theorem (Chapter VIII) on page 201 I couldn't solve the Exercise 1:

Prove the Corollary 1.14 if it is only assumed that $\overline{E}$ meets each component of $\mathbb{C}_{\infty} - G$.

Corollary 1.14) Let $G$ an open subset of the plane and let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb{C}_{\infty} -  {G}$ such that $E$ meets every component of
$\mathbb{C}_{\infty} -  G$. Let $R(G,E)$ be the set of rational funcions with poles in $E$ and consider $R(G,E)$ as a subspace of $H(G)$. If $f \in H(G)$ then there is a sequence $\{R_n \}$ in $R(G,E)$ such that $f = \lim R_n$. That is,
$R(G,E)$ is dense in $H(G)$.

A proof when E meets every component of $ \mathbb{C}_\infty - G$: Let K be a compact subset of G and $\epsilon > 0$; It must be show that there is an R in R(G,E) such that $|f(z) - R(z)|< \epsilon$ for all z in K. There is a compact K1 such that $ K \subset K1 \subset G$ and each component of $\mathbb{C}_\infty - K1$ contains a component of $\mathbb{C}_\infty - G$. Hence, E meets each component of $\mathbb{C}_\infty - K1$. The Corollary now follows from Runge's Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{C}_{\infty} \setminus G$ is closed, so $\overline{E} \subset \mathbb{C}_{\infty} \setminus G$ and we may follow the proof of the corollary that Conway gives, substituting $\overline{E}$ for $E$, up to the statement that $E$ meets each component of $\mathbb{C}_{\infty} \setminus K_1$. Since $K_1$ is compact, $\mathbb{C}_{\infty} \setminus K_1$ is open, and it follows that the components of $\mathbb{C}_{\infty} \setminus K_1$ are also open. Let $C$ be one such component, and let $\zeta \in \overline{E} \cap C$. Now, either $\zeta \in E$, or $\zeta$ is a limit point of $E$. In this latter case, there is a sequence $(z_n)$ of points in $E$ with $\lim z_n = \zeta$. However, since $C$ is open, this implies that there is some $z_k \in E \cap C$, and thus $E$ meets each component of $\mathbb{C}_{\infty} \setminus K_1$. An application of Runge's theorem again finishes the proof.